# How can I tell R's flextable to add linebreaks within words if necessary to fit my table in the available width?

Tags: r, shiny, flextable

I like the `flextable` package for R. I am using it to create tables for a Shiny app. Sometimes the tables occupy half the browser width, which might be quite a narrow space on some browsers. I would like to constrain `flextable` to not exceed its container width, even if this means inserting linebreaks within words.

Here is some example `flextable` code. Once you narrow the viewer window beyond a certain width, the `flextable` will not shrink further - instead the table will scroll horizontally.

```
library(magrittr)

mtcars %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("car") %>%
  flextable::flextable() %>%
  flextable::autofit()
```

The `reactable` package deals with this by inserting line breaks within words if necessary in order to remain within the maximum table width. This is often an ugly solution, but sometimes preferred.

```
mtcars %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("car") %>%
  reactable::reactable(defaultColDef = reactable::colDef(minWidth = 1))
```

Is there any way to get `flextable` to insert line breaks within words if that is necessary to not exceed the container width?

Comment: See the manual https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/layout-1.html#tabwidth? I think you want `set_table_properties(ft, layout = "autofit", width = 1)`

Comment: Thank you for your response @DavidGohel and thank you for your excellent packages. No, unfortunately this does not produce the behaviour I am looking for. Following your suggestion (or using `autofit()` as I did in my reprex) causes the Flextable to appropriately resize with its container until a certain narrow width is reached. It will not insert linebreaks within words to allow the table to go below that width.

Comment: For example, see below. If you run this, then resize the viewer so that it is quite narrow, the flextable will scroll horizontally rather than inserting linebreaks within words to keep to the container width. 

`mtcars %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("car") %>%
  flextable::flextable() %>%
  flextable::set_table_properties(layout = "autofit", width = 1)`

Comment: I am leaving the conversation, Given your answer, I think if I don't understand your issue. (I understood text should wrap, I think it is the case). On the manual, here: https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/datasets-used-for-illustrations.html#tennis-players, the text of the fist column is doing what I thought  you wanted

Comment: Thanks. I guess the answer is that it is not possible to get flextable to do what I want it to do. Note that I want text to wrap within words if necessary to preserve the table width (ie. linebreaks should be inserted within words if needed). The reactable example in my reprex demonstrates the desired result.

Comment: OK OK, you want to display a table on a very small width, let's say 15 pixels and the table should resize with available space even if it breaks words, and it should. It has been written to provide static table in HTML, docx, etc. If your users want to reduce the table to a size where words can be broken letters by letters, flextable is probably no able to do it. The used setting in flextable is "break-word".

Comment: I never thought about that maybe that's possible, but I think changing text overflow to something else than "break-word" will not be enough.